# How to render an audio file from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dictionary API that has a pronounciation feature (?). Here's an example with the word city
"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/city-us.mp3"

I have no idea how i can render it. I thought it was something like

```
 const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const soundApi = async () => {
    try {
      const soundData = await axios.get(
        `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/${input}-us.mp3`
      );

      console.log(soundData);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

And then the useEffect below it

```
useEffect(() => {
    dictionaryApi();
    soundApi();
  }, [input]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a audio element you can go like this

```
<audio
      controls
      src="https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/city-us.mp3"
      >
      Your browser does not support the
      <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but there is no need to fetch this url in order to display audio elements

Answer (score 0):

How Damian Busz said, its not necessary an api request to get audio file. But, Suposing that you need authentication for get this audio, and is using axios to get it, you could do the follow:

```
const [audioURI, setAudioURI] = useState("");
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

const soundApi = async () => {
    try {

      const response = await axios.get({
        url: `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/${input}-us.mp3`,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
      });

      // This will create a Local URL that can be used on an audio source
      const audioUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      setAudioURI(audioUrl);

      console.log(soundData);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

In your audio component:

```
{!!audioURI && (
<audio controls src={audioURI}>
      Your browser does not support the
      <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
)}
```

You can also return the URL value from the soundAPI functio

Comment: Could you explain to me that "Your browser" part?

Comment: Some (old) browsers cant render the native HTML audio player. When that happens, the content inside the <audio> element will be rendered. In this case, will inform that the current browser do not support <audio> element.